# Converting 8x8 board game to bytes

Tags: solidity, mapping, bytes, data-types

I'm trying to save memory by storing a game's 8x8 board as a binary value but am having trouble:

Each square on the board can be either `10` (black), `11` (white), or `00` (empty) and there are 64 squares. That's 128 binary digits so this should be 16 bytes (128/8) right?

How do I handle that in solidity? Would I say `bytes16 foo = 0b10111000...`?

Anyone have a link or advice with working directly with bytes in solidity?

Ultimately I'd like to use them as keys in a mapping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So BigNumber has really helpful base change operations. For anyone it might be helpful for here's what I did:

`var board = 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbwbbwbwbbbbwwwwbbbbbbbbbbwbwwbwbww-bbbbwwwwwwwwww'
boardConverted (board) {
  return board && '0b' + (board.match(/.{1,1}/g).map((spot) => {
    return spot === 'b' ? '11' : (spot === 'w' ? '10' : '00')
  }).join(''))
}
bin2hex (val) {
  if (!val) return
  var foo = new web3.BigNumber(val, 2)
  return foo.toString(16)
}
hex2bin (val) {
  if (!val) return
  var foo = new web3.BigNumber(val, 16)
  return foo.toString(2)
}
var hex = bin2hex(boardConvert(board))
var backToBin = hex2bin(hex)`